# get all records from TABLE_A that are not in TABLE_B and with a condition in TABLE_C

Tags: sql

Basically the question is to

Get all records from TABLE_A that are not in TABLE_B and has [id] corresponding to field [type] in TABLE_C

The table layout looks like this

```
TABLE_A
    id
    ref_id

TABLE_B
    id

TABLE_C
    id
    type
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A t1
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.ref_id IN ['id1', #paramId]
AND type IN (SELECT id FROM TABLE_C WHERE type = #paramType)
```

It might work (though I did not test) but I do not like that inner `select`.
Is there a way to avoid it using `join`s?

Comment: `Type` field is in which table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `INNER JOIN` instead :

```
SELECT t1.* FROM TABLE_A t1
INNER JOIN TABLE_C t3
 ON(t1.type = t3.id and t3.type = #paramType)
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B t2
 ON (t1.id = t2.id)
WHERE  t2.id is null
   AND t1.ref_id IN ('id1', #paramId)
```

I added this condition:

```
    WHERE  t2.id is null
```

To filter out those who exists in table 3.

Comment: but does it really need filtering `table_3` fields in `table_2`?

Comment: What do you mean? This query select all where a record exists in table 3 with the same id and with your param value, and where a record doesn't exists in table 2 . @user1432980

Comment: but won't LEFT JOIN select all the records that does not exist in table_2 by itseft without explicit need in check on `null`?

Comment: Yes, but it will also select all the records that does exists. Those who doesn't exists will have `NULL` value on `ID` column, therefore - the condition . Unless you want those who exists as well? @user1432980

Comment: Oh I see. So it will return records with `NULL` ids.